# Trying to install server ubuntu LTS 20.4on HP ProLight DL 380p ACPI Error AE_NOT_EXIST

Tags: server, hp, acpi

I am trying to install Ubuntu server on an HP ProLight DL380p,  I am getting several different types of ACPI error, e.g.

AE_NOT_EXIST _Evaluating, _PMM (20190816/power_meter-325),
No handler for Region [POWR] (00000000000aa4ccbe7) [IPMI] (20190816/evregion-127), etc

Running dmesg does report an error

ACPI Bios warning (bug): invalid length  for FADT/Pm1aControlBlock:32 using default 16 (20190816/tbfadt-669)

No other 'errors' are reported

Most of the advice I have seen of the subject advises to turn ACPI off in the grub boot script.

This being a server install , it does not seem to uses grub, i.e. no /etc/default/grub, no obvious grub menu on boot etc(Please correct me if I am wrong).

I am used to install Ubuntu on desktop systems, this is my first headless server

The comments on desktop Ubuntu system with ACPI errors seems to imply its a MS required feature.

1. Its been suggested that I can ignore it, is this correct ?
2. Have I correctly installed Ubuntu ?
3. Do I have a duff computer ?

The machine is listed as being able run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit, see https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201309-14186

Answer (score 0):

My first install include docker and as the default mini8 offering.

Having reinstalled, not included docker and repartition the disk, the error seems to have gone away.  So I am going to let sleeping dogs lie